# Possible to use Django templates '_set.all' against a GenericForeignKey-object?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, generic-foreign-key

I have a bunch of objects of Model A (which really aren't important..), and i have a model B, located in another app.

Model B refers to other objects as such:

```
content_object  = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

I'm only interested in the objects that hold references to types of Model A.
Would it be possible to (somehow) use the template 'backwards'-functionality to retrieve them?

i've tried:

```
 {% for a in objectA.objectB_set.all %}
 and so on..
```

But it doesn't seem to work with 'generics'..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a real relationship, so objectA doesn't know anything about the B objects. You need to define a [`GenericRelation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations) to ModelA to point back to B.